# Python mmap 'Permission denied' on Linux

Tags: python, mmap, permission-denied

I have a really large file I'm trying to open with mmap and its giving me permission denied.  I've tried different flags and modes to the `os.open` but its just not working for me.

What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> import os,mmap
>>> mfd = os.open('BigFile', 0)
>>> mfile = mmap.mmap(mfd, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
mmap.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
>>>
```

(using the built in `open()` works via the python docs example, but it seems to open more than one handle to the file both in read & write mode.  All i need for the `mmap.mmap` method is the file number, so I wouldn't assume i need to create a `file` object; hence my attempt at using `os.open()`)

Comment: Silly question, but do you have read permission on the file?

Comment: Why'd you open the file via `os.open` rather than the builtin `open()`?  Size?  For ~50 MB files (may be small relative to you) that I scanned through with re, the builtin worked fine for me after incorporating `prot=mmap.PROT_READ` as per Bobby.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think its a flags issue, try opening as read only:

```
mfd = os.open('BigFile', os.O_RDONLY)
```

and mmap.mmap by default tries to map read/write, so just map read only:

```
mfile = mmap.mmap(mfd, 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
```

Comment: By default os.open() opens the file as read-only, so you don't need the "os.O_RDONLY". The important thing is the "prot=mmap.PROT_READ", since you cannot memory-map a file with write permissions, if the file has been opened with read-only permissions.

Comment: @senarvi - the python 2 docs say 'The default mode is 0777 (octal), and the current umask value is first masked out' - http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open , so whether the file gets open RO or RW seems dependent on your umask if you omit the mode.

Comment: Oh you're right. I didn't notice that we're not using the built-in open().

Answer (score 12):

Try setting the file mode to `r+`. That worked for me on Linux:

```
mfd = os.open('BigFile', "r+")
```

Then this worked for me as normal:

```
mfile = mmap.mmap(mfd, 0)
```

Comment: I was trying `open('foo.txt', 'rwb')`. Thanks for saving my sanity.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart; you're welcome! The flags make no sense to me

Answer (score 6):

In my case this error occurred because I was attempting to open a block device without specifying an explicit size.

FWIW you cannot use `os.stat` / `os.fstat` with a block device to obtain the device's size (which is always 0), but you can use `file.seek` and `file.tell`:

```
f = file("/dev/loop0", "rb")
f.seek(0, 2)  # Seek relative to end of file
size = f.tell()
fh = f.fileno()

m = mmap.mmap(f, size, mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ)
```

Comment: Do you mean `f = open("/dev/loop0", "rb")` and `size = f.tell()`?

Comment: Oops, yes it should be `size = f.tell()` I'll fix that. As for `file()` versus `open()`, in Python2 `file()` is valid and I slightly prefer it over `open()` so I'll leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

The **cross-platform call** of `mmap` can be performed using `access` parameter:

```
mfd = os.open('BigFile', os.O_RDONLY)
mm = mmap.mmap(mfd, 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

The mmap construction permissions should be synced with the file open permissions (both read, write, or read/write).